# How do you run Gulp tasks on a remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, gulp, rsync

At my work we have multiple developers using a remote development server for testing and new development. I would like to use Gulp for front end builds on this server.

I copied a project from the remote server to a local environment and created a Gulp project. Locally everything works fine... The problem is: how do I transfer this to the remote development server? I can copy over the gulpfile, but how can I execute tasks from the remote server to deploy in that environment?

This is my gulpfile:

```
// modules
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const deporder = require('gulp-deporder');
const stripdebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

// globals
var devBuild = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production');

// sources
var project = {
    src: {
        base: 'src/',
        headScripts: [
        'src/js/general.js',
        'src/js/showhide.js',
        'src/js/validate-creditcard.js',
        'src/js/validate-Ascii.js',
        'src/js/functions.js',
        'src/js/parent-child-checker.js',
        'src/js/checkForm/checkName.js',
        'src/js/checkForm/checkAddress.js',
        'src/js/checkForm/checkContact.js',
        'src/js/checkForm/checkProfessional.js',
        'src/js/checkForm/checkMembership.js',
        'src/js/checkForm/checkPersonalForm-prof.js'
        ],
        css: [
        'src/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'src/css/blessed.css',
        'src/css/form-responsive.css'
        ]
    },
    build: 'dist/'
};

// JavaScript processing
gulp.task('js', function() {

  var jsbuild = gulp.src(project.src.headScripts)
    .pipe(deporder())
    .pipe(concat('main.js'));

  if (!devBuild) {
    jsbuild = jsbuild
      .pipe(stripdebug())
      .pipe(uglify());
  }

  return jsbuild.pipe(gulp.dest(project.build + 'js/'));

});

// CSS processing
gulp.task('css', function() {

  var cssbuild = gulp.src(project.src.css)
  .pipe(concat("main.css"))
  .pipe(autoprefixer());

  if (!devBuild) {
    cssbuild = cssbuild
      .pipe(cssnano());
  }

  return cssbuild.pipe(gulp.dest(project.build + 'css/'));

});

// default task
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css'], function() {

  // javascript changes
  gulp.watch(project.src.base + 'js/**/*', ['js']);

  // css changes
  gulp.watch(project.src.base + 'css/**/*', ['css']);

});
```

I know you can use rsync to create a Gulp task that deploys to a remote server through ssh like [this one](https://gist.github.com/plasticbrain/b98b5c3b97e7226353ce), but that is not what I am looking for. Development is done directly on the remote server by multiple developers - copying everything down to my local and trying to maintain synchronization between that and the remote development server would be an error prone burden. Also, how would other developers be able to run the tasks if they were only on my local?

Comment: Did you solve it? If you solved it could you provide the solution?